# How do I use sympy to extract value of a boolean variable in terms of other variables in a system of boolean equations?

Tags: python, sympy, z3, boolean-algebra

I have a system of boolean equations (example given below)

```
p = x & ~y
q = x & y
```

Now, I want to obtain the expression of `x` in terms of other variables in the system (LHS variables if possible) or to find that it can not be obtained. Is this possible in *sympy* (or *z3*?)?

```py
import sympy as s
p,q = s.symbols('p,q')
x,y = s.symbols('x,y')
v = s.And(s.Eq(p,x & y), s.Eq(q,x & ~y))
```

I have looked at `solve()` and `solveset()` but they seem to be dealing with linear equations.

```
>>> s.solveset(v, x)
    raise ValueError("%s is not a valid SymPy expression" % f)
ValueError: Eq(p, x & y) & Eq(q, x & ~y) is not a valid SymPy expression
```

Is there any other alternative?

I really do not understand the [documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html). According to it, the following should have worked, because it clearly says that in `sympy.solvers.solvers.solve(f, *symbols, **flags)`, f can be a *relational expression* or a *boolean*.

```py
>>> s.And(s.Equivalent(p, x &y), s.Equivalent(q, x&~y)).simplify()
(x | ~p) & (x | ~q) & (y | ~p) & (~p | ~q) & (~q | ~y) & (p | q | ~x) & (q | y | ~x) & (p | ~x | ~y)

>>> s.solve(s.And(s.Equivalent(p, x &y), s.Equivalent(q, x&~y)),x)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'And' and 'int'

>>> s.solveset(s.And(s.Equivalent(p, x &y), s.Equivalent(q, x&~y)),x)
ValueError: (Equivalent(p, x & y)) & (Equivalent(q, x & ~y)) is not a valid SymPy expression
```

Comment: I'm not sure about sympy. But you cannot do these sorts of simplifications in z3 in general. It will *simplify* expressions as per it's internal invariants, but it will not be in any form you'd consider simplified. SMT solvers aren't usually good for this sort of problem.

Comment: @alias, found that I could translate the [boolean expression to integer domain](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220314229_Solution_of_systems_of_Boolean_equations_via_the_integer_domain), and solve it using sympy.

Comment: In the SMT context, that would be a terrible thing to do: SAT/SMT solvers work a lot better with pure booleans compared to integers, in general. But perhaps that's the best way to go with sympy.